# How to update a nested type in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I have a document that contains a question and as a nested type all answers are added.  See example below.

I have the following questions:

How would I update one of the answers ?  I know there is the update api, but I cannot find a way to find for example the answer with id 88 and then change the text of this answer.

```
{
   "_index": "customer",
   "_type": "question",
   "_id": "8",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
      "id": 8,
      "title": "Question title",  
      "content": "The question text itself",              
      "answers": [
         {
            "answer_id": 42,                     
            "text": "Answer text 1"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 88,                    
            "text": "Answer text 2"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 79,                     
            "text": "Answer text 3"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 80,                    
            "text": "Answer text 4"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 8,                      
            "text": "Answer text 5"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% confident but I think you cannot do positional update with ES. You can add a string to an array [as the docs say](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) but I guess the only way is reindexing the document. Unfortunately ES does not cope greatly (e.g. like MongoDB) with nested docs (yet).

Comment: Maybe this post can help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/tI9I02raQoU Still I would think hard if this is really what you want want. How often are the the answers changed? If this is done regularly parent child might be a better a fit. If it happens once a while, obtain the document, change it and put it back in might be the best solution. You can even use the version to see make the update more or less atomic. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx Jettro.  This is exactly what I was also thinking.  We have now implemented parent child.